# How can I register generic class as IHttpModule

Tags: asp.net, fluent-nhibernate

```
public class NHibernateSessionPerRequest<T>:IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += BeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += EndRequest;
    }
}
```

How can it be registered in web.config?

Comment: It can be any type of repository classes.

Comment: So you're going to have a session-per-request-per-repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS6 : In the system.web section of your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="MyModule" type="My.Namespace.NHibernateSessionPerRequest`1[[My.Namespace.MyType, My.Assembly]], My.Assembly"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

IIS7 : In the system.webserver section of your web.config :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="MyModule" type="My.Namespace.NHibernateSessionPerRequest`1[[My.Namespace.MyType, My.Assembly]], My.Assembly"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For both, replace "My.Namespace" with the namespace of the class, and "My.Assembly" with the assembly name.

Comment: I don't think that this addresses the problem of the module type being generic. Both of your config samples show a non-generic type being registered.

Comment: yup, didn't see it when I was writing it. Corrected now

Comment: So I'd have to register actual types. This seams to be similar to Eilon's solution. Ideally would be if I didn't have to create non generic IHttpModule for every existing type.

Comment: Both solutions have advantages. Here you don't need to create derived type of you HttpModule.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to create a concrete type that derives from this type, and then register that:

```
public class MyActualModule : NHibernateSessionPerRequest<SomeType> {
}
```

Then in web.config register MyActualModule.

Alternatively, you can use the CLR-compliant syntax for generic types, but it's so awful that I won't even mention it here. Even a simple type like yours will have a type name that's probably over 100 chars long.